Route Mapping in Flask - Python
I have this html file with some contents as:
<tbody>
            {% for task in tasks %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ task.task_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.date }}</td>
                <td>
                    {% if task.volunteer_ids %}
                        {{ task.volunteer_ids | join(", ") }}
                    {% else %}
                        No volunteers assigned
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {% for event in events %}
                        {% if event.event_id == task.event_id %}
                            {{ event.name }}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('task.edit_task', task_id=task['task.task_id']) }}">Edit</a> |
                    <form action="{{ url_for('task.delete_task', task_id=task['task.task_id']) }}" method="POST" style="display:inline;">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>

Now, if I click on edit/delete button, it is not passing the task_id with the URL, and the function is not working.
This is the route file for both edit_task and delete_task.
    @task_bp.route('/edit_task/<task_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_task(task_id):
    task = mongo.db.tasks.find_one({'task_id': task_id})

    if not task:
        flash("Task not found!", "error")
        return redirect(url_for('task.task_management'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        updated_name = request.form.get('task_name')
        updated_description = request.form.get('task_description')
        updated_date = request.form.get('task_date')
        updated_event_id = request.form.get('task_event_id')
        updated_volunteer_ids = request.form.getlist('task_volunteer_ids')

        if not updated_name or not updated_date or not updated_event_id:
            flash("Task name, date, and associated event are required!", "error")
            return redirect(url_for('task.edit_task', task_id=task_id))

        try:
            # Update the task in the database
            mongo.db.tasks.update_one(
                {'task_id': task_id},
                {
                    '$set': {
                        'name': updated_name,
                        'description': updated_description,
                        'date': updated_date,
                        'event_id': updated_event_id,
                        'volunteer_ids': updated_volunteer_ids
                    }
                }
            )
            flash("Task updated successfully!", "success")
        except Exception as e:
            flash(f"An error occurred while updating the task: {e}", "error")

        return redirect(url_for('task.task_management'))

    events = list(mongo.db.events.find())
    volunteers = list(mongo.db.volunteers.find())

    return render_template(
        'admin/edit_task.html',
        task=task,
        events=events,
        volunteers=volunteers
    )

# Route: Delete Task
@task_bp.route('/delete_task/<task_id>', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_task(task_id):
    try:
        # Delete the task from the database
        mongo.db.tasks.delete_one({'task_id': task_id})
        flash("Task deleted successfully!", "success")
    except Exception as e:
        flash(f"An error occurred while deleting the task: {e}", "error")

    return redirect(url_for('task.task_management'))


try changing this line this <a href="{{ url_for('task.edit_task', task_id=task.task_id) }}">Edit</a>
